# EntityDataModelEmbeddedResources parameter is not supported by the EntityDeploy task

Tags: .net, msbuild

On some computers (and some others not!) I'm getting this error from MSBuild 4.0 when building a 3.5 solution:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Data.Entity.targets(43,7): error MSB4131: The "EntityDataModelEmbeddedResources" parameter is not supported by the "EntityDeploy" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a gettable public instance property. [C:\prg\myproject.csproj]

This project doesn't even use EF and the csproj doesn't reference that 'targets' file anywhere.

Has anyone seen this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is less than ideal, but as a workaround, I just removed the contents of the EntityDeploy target in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Data.Entity.targets . It works. Hopefully someone will come along here with a better solution and a reasonable explanation for this.

Answer (score 1):

I actually had this problem thrown today with a project I was messing with. Turns out simply replacing `"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319"` with `"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5"` in my `PATH` I got a clean build.

If other people are having trouble and have .Net 3.5 and 4 installed, you may want to try changing your path vars and calling the other version of msbuild. Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction with this.

Answer (score 0):

Solution on this site may resolve this issue...
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/idof/archive/2008/11/24/what-does-entity-framework-has-to-do-with-msbuild.aspx

However, this may be a conflict with version 4.0 and 3.5 of the Build Framework.

So a version of App.Config that should work is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
   <runtime>
     <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Framework"
                  publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
     </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm only calling msbuild from the command line, not using it through code as explained in that article...